# Input error in PHP file

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to hide a form based on a button click. Below is my code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Programma per connettersi a un database tramite il linguaggio PHP
  </title>
  <style>
    #mybutton {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 50px 0;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: orange;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="button()">Inserisci studente</button>

  <div id="mybutton">
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> Nome Studente:<br>
      <input name="Nome" type="text" value="" placeholder="Inserisci il 
         nome dello studente" size="30" /><br> Cognome Studente:<br>
      <input name="Cognome" type="text" value="" placeholder="Inserisci 
         il cognome dello studente" size="30" /><br> Eta Studente:<br>
      <input name="Eta" type="integer" value="" placeholder="Inserisci 
         l'età dello studente" size="30" /><br>
      <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Inserisci" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br>

  <button onclick="button()">Aggiorna nome</button>

  <div id="mybutton">
    Inserisci il nome dello studente da modificare nello spazio sottostante
    <br>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> Nuovo Nome:<br>
      <input name="NewName" type="text" value="" placeholder="Inserisci il 
     nuovo nome" size="30" /><br> Vecchio Nome:<br>
      <input name="OldName" type="text" value="" placeholder="Inserisci il 
     nome attuale" size="30" /><br>
      <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Aggiornare" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function button() {
      var x = document.getElementById('mybutton');
      if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

When the first button is clicked, everything works as expected, but in the second case when I press the button "Aggiorna nome", the form doesn't hide.
Why does the first button work and the second does not?

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID. ID's must be unique withing the whole document. If _do_ have multiple elements with the same ID, it will always use the first element.

Comment: You also need to close your forms. You open two but you aren't closing any.

Comment: @SvenTheSurfer - When you propose an edit, _don't change the original code_. Your edit completely removed the form elements, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code:

1) Same ID for 2 different elements ('mybutton').

2) The form tags are not closed properly, so the button submit the form.

Here I fixed up your code so it works:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Programma per connettersi a un database tramite il linguaggio 
        PHP</title>
    <style>
        .mybutton {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 50px 0;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: orange;
            margin-top:20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <button data-id="first-div" onclick="button(this)">Inserisci studente</button>

    <div id= "first-div" class="mybutton">
        <form action = "DatabaseManagerMySQL.php?operation_type = insert" method 
              = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
            <input type ="hidden" name = "action" value = "submit">
            Nome Studente:<br>
            <input name = "Nome" type = "text" value = "" placeholder="Inserisci il 
                   nome dello studente" size = "30"/><br>
            Cognome Studente:<br>
            <input name = "Cognome" type = "text" value = "" placeholder="Inserisci 
                   il cognome dello studente" size = "30"/><br>
            Eta Studente:<br>
            <input name = "Eta" type = "integer" value = "" placeholder="Inserisci 
                   l'età dello studente" size = "30"/><br>
            <input type= "submit" name = "insert" value = "Inserisci"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>

    <button data-id="second-div" onclick = "button(this)">Aggiorna nome</button>

    <div id = "second-div" class="mybutton">
        Inserisci il nome dello studente da modificare nello spazio sottostante
        <br>
        <form action = "DatabaseManagerMySQL.php?operation_type = update" method = 
              "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
            <input type ="hidden" name = "action" value = "submit">
            Nuovo Nome:<br>
            <input name = "NewName" type = "text" value = "" placeholder="Inserisci il 
                   nuovo nome" size = "30"/><br>
            Vecchio Nome:<br>
            <input name = "OldName" type = "text" value = "" placeholder="Inserisci il 
                   nome attuale" size = "30"/><br>
            <input type= "submit" name = "insert" value = "Aggiornare"/>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        function button(obj) {
            var divId = obj.getAttribute("data-id");
            var x = document.getElementById(divId);
            if (x.style.display === 'none') {
                x.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                x.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

What i did is to use a class instead of an Id for your elements and add the `data-id` to the button so the JS functions receives the element's id and knows what element should hide or whatever you like to do.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour for `button` elements is to submit the form they are placed in.

To prevent this behaviour, you can add the type="button" attribute to your button. This way your javascript code will be executed.

```
<button type="button" onclick="button()">Aggiorna nome</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use many IDs with same value

> https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute The id attribute
>   specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The value must be
>   unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must
>   contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space
>   characters.

Use class instead.

2. Check your IDE, it seems that it adds spaces before and after "=" inadequately. I bet there shouldn't be any spaces in `"DatabaseManagerMySQL.php?operation_type = insert"`

**Answer:**

You didn't close the first `<form>` tag, that's why first button (the "Aggiorna nome" one) in that form acts like sumbit button (behaviour by default) and submits to `"DatabaseManagerMySQL.php?operation_type = insert"`

Comment: Just a note, the OP doesn't close the second form either.

Comment: Yep, he will open second question in a while then

Answer (score 0):

In your code have some problem

```
1. you missing </form> // close form tag in both form
2. you use same id in main content div so it will not work
3. you use same id in your javascript function so next form will not work
```

so need to fixed

```
so fixed close tag, use 2 id and send this id in onclick button function id name so one function will fixed issue
```

```js
function button(form_div) {
        var x = document.getElementById(form_div);
        if (x.style.display === 'none') {
            x.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            x.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Programma per connettersi a un database tramite il linguaggio
        PHP</title>
    <style>
        #mybutton {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 50px 0;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: orange;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="button('mybutton1')" type="button">Inserisci studente</button>

<div id="mybutton1">
    <form action="DatabaseManagerMySQL.php?operation_type = insert" method
    ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
        Nome Studente:<br>
        <input name="Nome" type="text" value="" placeholder="Inserisci il
     nome dello studente" size="30"/><br>
        Cognome Studente:<br>
        <input name="Cognome" type="text" value="" placeholder="Inserisci
     il cognome dello studente" size="30"/><br>
        Eta Studente:<br>
        <input name="Eta" type="integer" value="" placeholder="Inserisci
     l'età dello studente" size="30"/><br>
        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Inserisci"/>
</form>    
</div>

<br><br><br>

<button onclick="button('mybutton2')" type="button">Aggiorna nome</button>

<div id="mybutton2">
    Inserisci il nome dello studente da modificare nello spazio sottostante
    <br>

    <form action="DatabaseManagerMySQL.php?operation_type = update" method=
    "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
        Nuovo Nome:<br>
        <input name="NewName" type="text" value="" placeholder="Inserisci il
 nuovo nome" size="30"/><br>
        Vecchio Nome:<br>
        <input name="OldName" type="text" value="" placeholder="Inserisci il
 nome attuale" size="30"/><br>
        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Aggiornare"/>
</form>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope, this code still submits form. You didn't even test it, right?

Comment: Add `type="button"` on the buttons.

Comment: @iXCray please check now

Comment: Getting closer, now it's only missing a couple of `</form>`-tags. (and the fact that the CSS now styles non-existent elements).

Answer (score -1):

A quick solution would be to simply create a separate javascript function making sure the Div ids are different. The below code is similar to the one posted but (i) include a new javascript function and (2) new Div ids.

This code enables to have two buttons to hide the divs.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Programma per connettersi a un database tramite il linguaggio 
 PHP</title>
  <style>
  .mybutton {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-top:20px;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <button onclick="button()">Inserisci studente</button>

    <div id= "mybutton" class="mybutton">
    <form action = "DatabaseManagerMySQL.php?operation_type = insert" method 
     = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    <input type ="hidden" name = "action" value = "submit">
    Nome Studente:<br>
    <input name = "Nome" type = "text" value = "" placeholder="Inserisci il 
     nome dello studente" size = "30"/><br>
    Cognome Studente:<br>
    <input name = "Cognome" type = "text" value = "" placeholder="Inserisci 
     il cognome dello studente" size = "30"/><br>
    Eta Studente:<br>
   <input name = "Eta" type = "integer" value = "" placeholder="Inserisci 
     l'et? dello studente" size = "30"/><br>
   <input type= "submit" name = "insert" value = "Inserisci"/>
 </div>
 <br><br><br>

<button onclick="button2();">Aggiorna nome</button>

<div id = "mybutton2" class="mybutton">
Inserisci il nome dello studente da modificare nello spazio sottostante
<br>
<form action = "DatabaseManagerMySQL.php?operation_type = update" method = 
 "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
<input type ="hidden" name = "action" value = "submit">
Nuovo Nome:<br>
<input name = "NewName" type = "text" value = "" placeholder="Inserisci il 
 nuovo nome" size = "30"/><br>
Vecchio Nome:<br>
<input name = "OldName" type = "text" value = "" placeholder="Inserisci il 
 nome attuale" size = "30"/><br>
 <input type= "submit" name = "insert" value = "Aggiornare"/>
 </div>

 <script>
   function button() {
    var x = document.getElementById('mybutton');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
         x.style.display = 'block';
    }else{
         x.style.display = 'none';
      }
     }

   function button2() {
    var x = document.getElementById('mybutton2');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
         x.style.display = 'block';
    }else{
         x.style.display = 'none';
      }
     } 

   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to include an explanation on what you've changed and why. Otherwise, it's the code version of "Where's Waldo".